# Solving the inequality ${x^2+2x+2^{|a|}\over x^2-a^2} > 0$

Tags: inequality, quadratics

How do I solve the inequality ${x^2+2x+2^{|a|}\over x^2-a^2} > 0$?

My idea is that for $a\ne 1$, the numerator will always be positive. So the inequality reduces to $
{1 \over x^2-a^2 } > 0
$
My doubt is in this part. If we factorise the denominator, we get
$
{1 \over (x+a)(x-a)}
$
which, by using the wavy curve method, gives me,
$
x \epsilon (-\infty,-a) \  \ \ \cup \ \ \ (a,\infty).
$

But according to my textbook, the answer with $a\ne1$ is 
$
x \epsilon (-\infty,-|a|) \  \ \ \cup \ \ \ (|a|,\infty).
$
Why?

Comment: hint : ${1 \over x^2-a^2 } = {1 \over (x+|a|)(x-|a|)}$

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your solution you can have the $2$ intervals ovelapping, i.e. $-a > a$ which holds for all $a<0$

Hence in order for the intervals to not overlap, you have to use the modulus

Comment: Could you slightly elaborate?

Comment: You have to solve $x^2-a^2>0 \Leftrightarrow (x-a)(x+a)>0$ and you've concluded that $x \in (-\infty, -a) \bigcup (a, \infty)$ which implies that $-a<a$ as one is the right end of the first interval, while the second is the left end of the second interval. You can see that this is problematic if $a<0$. To avoid this, solve it as $(x^2-a^2)=(x-|a|)(x+|a|)$ and now you know for sure that $-|a|\leq |a|$ and the intervals will not overlap

Answer (score 1):

Your textbook is right.

For instance, take $a=-1$. Your solution would be $(-\infty,1)\cup(-1,\infty)=\mathbb R$, which is wrong.

In fact, the solution *must* be in terms of $|a|$, as the sign of $a$ plays no role.